# Why do I get EXC_BAD_ACCESS even though the pointer appears to be valid?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, exc-bad-access

I start with an integer array `test[]` which represents a set of images.  The first two elements of `test[]` are the height and width of the first image.  The following four `(height*width)` elements are pixel values.  The next six represent the next image and so on.

My goal is to access the images through image objects without duplicating anything in the `test[]` array. I try to do this via `ImageSet::import`.

```
int main(){
    int test[] = {2,2,1,2,3,4,
                  2,2,4,5,6,7,
                  2,2,9,8,0,9};
    ImageSet set = ImageSet();
    set.import(test); //ImageSet::import
    return 0;
}
```

`ImageSet::import` uses the cursor variable to store the start index of the next image.
it calls `Image::import` to read that data into an image object.  The data for that particular image should start at the address `&data[cursor]`.

```
void ImageSet::import(int data[]){
    int cursor = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < NUM_SRC_IMAGES; i++){
        int height = data[cursor];
        int width = data[cursor+1];
        source_[i].import(&data[cursor]); //this is Image::import
        cursor += height * width + 2;
    }
}
```

Within `image::import`, I get a bad access by attempting to read `data[0]`.  According to the debugger, `data[]` points to the correct value of 2, but `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` is thrown anyway when I attempt to get that value via `data[0]`.

```
void Image::import(int data[]){
    height_ = data[0]; //the problem occurs right here
    width_ = data[1];
    matrix_ = &data[2];
}
```

I would very much appreciate an explaination of what I am doing wrong.  I would equally appreciate suggestions for how to achive my goal without pointer arithmetic.

Thank You!

Comment: Have you tried passing it as `source_[i].import(data + cursor)`?

Comment: A complete program please. http://sscce.org

Comment: Add couple of print statements after `for(int i = 0; i < NUM_SRC_IMAGES; i++){` to print `i` and `cursor` to make sure that you are not trying to access memory beyond what you are supposed to.

Comment: Problem reading data[0] or problem writing height_?

Comment: Why don't you use const? Why don't you use iterators? Are you sure that i<NUM_SRC_IMAGES is the right condition and that there really are NUM_SRC_IMAGES images in test (or are you reading past the end of test)?

Comment: Please please use an std::vector instead of arrays and pointers. `vector<int> data; data.reserve(15);  data.push_back(...);` isnt so much more effort, and it allows you size-checking. Calling `vector.at(cursor)` is immediately going to throw an out of bounds exception, and it allows you to use an `assert(cursor < data.size());` before dereferencing an out-of-bounds memory location and passing its address. See my detailed answer if you don't want to change the type.

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that during the optimization phase the compiler rearranges your loop to

```
for(int i = 0; i < NUM_SRC_IMAGES; i++){
    source_[i].import(&data[cursor]); //this is Image::import
    int height = data[cursor];   // -> would also crash, but you don't see it because import crashes earlier
    int width = data[cursor+1];
    cursor += height * width + 2;
}
```

And since you defined NUM_SRC_IMAGES too large you are reading past the end of test.

BTW, you should also think about using STL like iterator style and then call `set.import(begin(test), end(test));` By abstracting from the underlying type you could read data from any container. And you can check against the end so you never read past the end.

Answer (score 0):

With the limited information in the question, I can suggest the following:

1. try changing import to be `ImageSet::import(const int* data, size_t size)` or... preferably, `ImageSet::import(const int (&data[18]))` - this allows for a clear reference as opposed to a data[] which *can* be optimized away under some circumstances. The latter also explicitly specifies to your fellow devs that it is an array reference (as opposed to a pointer). Same for `Image::import`.
2. In `Image::import` print out the value of `data` (i.e. `&data[0]`) - this will let you know if the address is valid.
3. at the end of the loop in `ImageSet::import` print out the value of `cursor`.

My guess is in the third loop or so, the value of `cursor` grows too large, greater than 18. I don't know what your intention is... but that `cursor += 3 + 4*2` logic (as an example) looks real suspicious.